# S4 exports specified in 'NAMESPACE' but not defined in package

Tags: r, r-package

I just finished some minor updates to an R package I've had on CRAN for a few years (haven't had to update in a while).  My package passes Check on my local machine and on winbuilder, but it just bounced back from CRAN with the message

```
checking whether package 'riverdist' can be installed ... WARNING
Found the following significant warnings:
  Warning: S4 exports specified in 'NAMESPACE' but not defined in package 'riverdist'
```

I use roxygen2 to build my package NAMESPACE and don't have any S4 exports that I'm aware of.

Perhaps this might be related to changes in R version 4.0.0?

If anyone's encountered this error, I'd love to hear how you were able to resolve it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved. roxygen2's `@exportClass` adds to NAMESPACE `exportClasses()` which is intended for S4 classes. S3 classes do not need to be exported, only constructor and method functions should be exported, and this is done using `@export`. In my case deleting all `@exportClass` commands solved the problem as my package defines only S3 classes. So, indeed the WARNING message is correct in diagnosing S4 exports. Found answer with the help [from a thread in R-package-devel mail list](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-package-devel/2020q2/005482.html) from yesterday.

In the case of my packages, the problem existed in only one package that the other 9 which were also triggering the warning depend on.

The WARNING is triggered only under r-devel (future R 4.1.0).

Answer (score 1):

I received this message from rdevel

"This is a new check in R-devel. The NEWS say:

> R CMD check etc now warn when a package exports non-existing S4 classes or methods, also in case of no "methods" presence

In your case, the NAMESPACE contains

> exportClasses(classify)
>
> exportClasses(gonad_mature)
>
> exportClasses(morphMat)

but your package does not define these S4 classes.

You seem to instruct roxygen2 to create these invalid directives using
@exportClass tags manually instead of just @export. Simply remove these
wrong @exportClass tags from your source files and regenerate your
NAMESPACE.

Best regards,

```
    Sebastian Meyer"
```

https://www.mail-archive.com/r-package-devel@r-project.org/msg05436.html

Comment: So, I am having exactly this same issue and do not have any instances of `@exportClass` or `@exportClasses` as I had specifically dealt with them in this package update. So, this does not appear to be the answer.

Comment: @JeffreyEvans could you share how you solve your case? I have similar. I am using @ export but roxygen2 generates me exportClasses(abc) which is not really making the class public.